# Formatting percentages

Tags: writing-style, percentages, format

According to the SI rules for percentages (http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) the value should always be separated from the % sign by a space; however, when writing text it always seems a little odd to include the space and I very rarely see it written that way.

My salary increased by 56 % last week.
My salary increased by 56% last week.

Is there a different rule for written English?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about typesetting rather than language. This is a [matter of style](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052). Either you have a house style and/or editor whose guidance you must adhere to, or you don't, and simply need to be clear and consistent. For what it's worth, APA and CMOS both omit the space. CMOS further says to use *“percent” for humanistic copy and the “%” symbol for scientific and statistical copy*.

Comment: You're probably right although my question, was asking whether there was an English language rule. So I would have thought that would have made it on topic even if the answer was no.

Answer (score 4):

Chicago Manual of Style, section  9.23 15th edition (p. 385) "Note also that no space appears between the numeral and the symbol %." So, I suppose it depends on the forum. If it is a scientific journal and they mandate SI rules, then use a space; if it is a book for a non-specialized audience then delete the space.